# html temporary notification message

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any way to show a message in HTML only for 2 seconds, in boxes similar to :
[image]

```
This item already does exist
```

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried?

Comment: looking for any single command made for that

Comment: it's called a growler, but what have you tried to use?

Comment: You need to show what you tried if you want others to give you assistance.

Comment: You want a **one-liner**? Not possible in plain HTML. I'd suggest using JavaScript (plain or jQuery / Zepto...). Easy doable with `setTimeout()`. _Google before you ask!!!_

Comment: @Charles380, `html growler example` gave me no result. i have no exprience and have no idea on even what to search on google!

Comment: @monjevin are you looking for a tooltip or a plain alert style box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get started [jQuery Growler](http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/)

Comment: This at best can be a comment. ( Ps I will not downvote)

Comment: @agstudy , but enough for me

Comment: @monjevin Maybe you can show us what you will do using this answer and post yours. I will be happy to upvote your detailed answer.

Comment: @agstudy i have a textbox using jquery to autocomplete items. once an item was selected, it should be appended into a box. if this item already exists in that box, a notification must inform the user without bothering him/her

Comment: @monjevin by detailed I mean `javascript/css/html code` not `text description`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's not possible with plain HTML(5).

However, it is using **CSS3 animations**! Just use it in combination with the animation **delay**.

### For example:

```
.tooltip {
    ...YOUR CSS HERE...
  
    /* The desired time (2 seconds) before the animation starts */
    -vendor-animation-delay: 2s;
    
    -vendor-animation-duration: 1s;
    -vendor-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -vendor-animation-name: fadeOut;
}

@-vendor-keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {opacity: 1;}    
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

I left out the browser prefixes like `-webkit-`, `-moz-` for readability. So, replace `-vendor-` with them.

Note that this only works in browsers that support CSS3. Check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS) for further compatibility information.

The animation css can also be written in one line, but I used this variant to show you the possible settings for css3 animations.

### Also have a look at:

- [CSS3 Please](http://css3please.com/)
- [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/)
- [HTML5 Timers](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/timers.html)

Happy coding!